# How to pass '--' to cli since according to the common rules it's mean end of args array?

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

When you want to pass an indefinite number of parameter in CLI, a common usage is to use -- :

`app --name foo bar -- other`

Now how do you do if you want to pass the string '--' ?

I didn't found what the "specs" say about this. Is this a limitation per design or is there any kind of escape syntax for cli parameter?

Comment: What shell do you refer to specifically? There's bash, zsh, PowerShell, and many others; each might have slight non-obvious differences. Also, CLI is a concept that applies to a particular program/process; for example, `node` CLI does not treat `--` any differently from other arguments

Comment: I don't specifically refer to a certain shell, I would refer to the state of the art, so is there any or like you seem to say every pogram implements their own cli specification ?

Comment: Yes, every program parses its command lines however it likes. There are common conventions, but no requirement to follow those conventions. A common trick for passing a file named `--` is to use a relative path: `./--`.